# Non removable battery beard trimmers in hand luggage

Tags: hand-luggage, trimmer

I am planning to carry my Phillips beard trimmer in hand luggage. Its battery is not removable.
Following are some of the points, I wanted to clarify:

- Are non removable trimmers allowed in hand luggage generally on all airlines/countries or rules can vary from country to country.
- Are trimmers with non removable battery generally allowed in checked in luggage.
- There have been times when I have seen trimmer just start on its own if it is charged. As battery is not removable, there is always chance of this. Are there any best practices around carrying trimmers?

Answer (score 3):

> Are non removable trimmers allowed in hand luggage generally

Yes

> ... on all airlines/countries or rules can vary from country to country.

Impossible to know for sure. Too many airlines and too many countries.

> Are trimmers with non removable battery generally allowed in checked in luggage.

Yes.

> There have been times when I have seen trimmer just start on its own if it is charged. As battery is not removable, there is always chance of this. Are there any best practices around carrying trimmers?

This is a similar problem as with electric toothbrushes and the details depend on the type and design of the switch. Sliders are mostly fine "as is". Push buttons can be protected with some tape with if they are reasonably well recessed. For sticky-out push buttons you will need some sort of a carrying case.